# Создать код, прошу, помогите студенту, пожалуйста, очень нужно

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

в программировании начинающий, прям начинающий. Нужно создать код :

есть два input. В одном (input1) стоит начальное значение = 1. Во второе поле (input2) человек вводит число.  есть две кнопки (кнопка1 прибавляет +1, кнопка2 отнимает -1). если пользователь ввел число в input2, большее чем в input1 и нажал на кнопку1, то действие выполняется и прибавляется +1, то есть значение становиться =2. Если человек ввел число меньшее, то сервер ищет другого пользователя, который также ввел недостаточное число, складывает их числа, если достаточно выполняет действие +1, если опять недостаточно, ищет другого и тд. когда пользователи нажимают на кнопку2, отнимается -1 и кнопка блокируется и становиться снова активной только после того, как значение увеличится на 2. То есть было, например, значение = 10, нажали на кнопку2 стало 10-1=9 и дальше кнопка2 станет активной только после того, как значение станет (9+2=)11. Нужно это все подвязать именно на значении, т.к. как уже написал выше, много пользователей будут нажимать на кнопку1, но если число недостаточное, значение не будет меняться. Я понимаю, что это займет время и силы, но очень прошу помочь, потому что студент и еще только начинаю, а сроки горят, думаю вы тоже были в такой ситуации и очень хорошо меня понимаете. Готов для "обсуждения" и т.д (в плане сотрудничества). Я написал код для html и javascript, но т.к. это будет что-то типа мини онлайн-игры, нужно подключать php b базу данных и ajax, а в этом я еще не разобрался. Вот код, написанный мной, можете менять ка хотите или вообще его не использовать, это не принципиально, главное сделать

это Html

```
<form>
<p><input class="form-control"  type="number"  value="1" id="res" readonly/></p>
    <p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary b go" onclick="return false">Отправить</button>
        <button data-counter="1" class="btn btn-danger b back"> Забрать </button>
    </p>
   <p><input id="resurs" type="number"></input>
```

это javascript

```
        $(function(){
            $('.b').click(function(){
                    var itog;
                    var number = parseInt($('#res').val());
                    var resurs = parseFloat($('#resurs').val());

                    if($(this).hasClass('go')){
                        if (resurs >= ( 1.0999 * number )) {
                            itog = number + 1;
                            var counter = parseInt($(this).next().attr('data-counter'));

                            if((itog - counter)>= 2){
                                    $(this).next().prop('disabled', false);
                            } 
                        }
                        else {
                            вот тут и начинаются загвоздки
                        }
                            }

                    else{
                            itog = number - 1;
                            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
                            $(this).attr('data-counter', itog);
                    }

                    $('#res').val(itog);
            })

    })
```

Comment: О-о-о, "очень нужно"! Чудесно. Мне очень нужны белые штаны и билет в Рио-де-Жанейро. Очень.

Comment: Я просто попросил о помощи, не более того, все мы бывали и будем в трудных ситуациях, и всем нам нужна поддержка в эти моменты.

Comment: извините, если оскорбил вас чем-то, но я думал, что это форум где сидят добрые люди и можно попросить о помощи

Comment: "это форум где сидят добрые люди" - отнюдь

Comment: Ну все-таки они везде должны быть)

Comment: У вас задача часов на 8 работы. Вы хотите, что бы мы целиком делали ее за вас?

Comment: Я написал, что готов сотрудничать и тд. Нужно  лишь найти того, кто это все может сделать